# Getting error while running ansible playbook

Tags: azure, ansible

Getting error in the ansible playbook while running the azure module

ImportError: cannot import name 'RecoveryServicesBackupClient' from 'azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/mgmt/recoveryservicesbackup/**init**.py)

Answer (score 0):

Running the pip command solved my problem.

```
pip install -r ~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt
```